# How to search assemblies for types that implement desired generic interface

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, immediate-window

I am searching through assemblies to identify any classes that implement a desired generic interface so I can dynamically instantiate an instance. This is the code I'm using:

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
var assemblyFormatters = types.Where(type => type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => 
   i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IInterface<>)));
```

The code works for a standard class:

```
public class Implementation : IInterface<object>
```

but not for a generic class:

```
public class GenericImplementation<T> : IInterface<T>
```

Event stranger, the code works successfully when run in the intermediate window, but not when run within a unit test framework. The immediate window returns 2 types, the test code run under the debugger returns only the non generic implementation.

I would expect both types to be returned by the code

Comment: If the code works, then it works. The problem is the unit test project I guess. Does that project have the correct references?

Comment: I thought so. Turns out that I was loading in assemblies from `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`, which gave the same assembly, but due to the way they were loaded the assemblies were different. I've moved to using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` which has resolved the issue. I will add it as the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is an issue with assemblies. I was loading in the assemblies using:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
foreach (var assembly in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
{
    Assembly.LoadFile(assembly);
}
```

When comparing the loaded assembly with Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), the assemblies are not equal. Since types have references to their respective assemblies, the types were therefore not equal. Moving to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` solved the problem, as I was loading assemblies already loaded by the application.